# How to both delete and add value from a set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Considering the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class MainEntity {
  /*...*/
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "mainEntity")
  private Set<SubEntity> subEntities = new LinkedHashSet<>();
  /*...*/
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
  @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"foo", "bar"})
})
public class SubEntity {
  /*...*/

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private MainEntity mainEntity;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String foo;

   @Column(nullable = false)
  private String bar;
  /*...*/
}
```

I create a new `MainEntity` with 1 `SubEntity` with `{foo:"a", bar:"b"}` and persist it.

```
MainEntity mainEntity = new MainEntity();
SubEntity sub = new SubEntity();
sub.setFoo("a");
sub.setBar("b");
sub.setMainEntity(mainEntity);
mainEntity.setSubEntities(new LinkedHashSet<>(sub));
entityManager.persist(mainEntity);
```

Then I update the `MainEntity` by dropping the above `SubEntity` and adding a new one with the exact same foo and bar.

I try to persist the `MainEntity` again.

```
SubEntity anotherSub = new SubEntity();
anotherSub.setFoo("a");
anotherSub.setBar("b");
anotherSub.setMainEntity(mainEntity);
// replace
mainEntity.setSubEntities(new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(anotherSub)));
entityManager.persist(mainEntity); // throws org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

I expect the initial `SubEntity` to be deleted and a new `SubEntity` to be added.

However, the very first query is adding the new `SubEntity` (before removing the old one) which does not work since there is a SQL unique constraint that is violated because the other `SubEntity` is not deleted yet.

What am I missing?

Comment: you dont show us any of the actions you have described: code for updating, dropping, persisting...

Comment: @JAsgarov I edited my inital question with a sample.

Comment: "Then I update the MainEntity by dropping the above SubEntity and adding a new one with the exact same foo and bar."  - missing code

Comment: @JAsgarov I actually did that by replacing the whole `Set`. See the code below `I try to persist the MainEntity again.`

Comment: try persisting it with empty linkedHashSet first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

| id | foo | bar | main_entry_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | 1 |

if you have the table like this with unique foo and bar, first you have to get the `id` of the previous entry and set it to the current entry `id`.
For example:

```
MainEntity mainEntity = new MainEntity();
SubEntity sub = new SubEntity();
sub.setFoo("a");
sub.setBar("b");
sub.setMainEntity(mainEntity);
mainEntity.setSubEntities(new LinkedHashSet<>(sub));
MainEntity mainEntityResult = entityManager.persist(mainEntity);

SubEntity anotherSub = new SubEntity();
anotherSub.setFoo("a");
anotherSub.setBar("b");
anotherSub.setMainEntity(mainEntity);
Long subEntryId = SubEntryService.getIdbyFoo(mainEntityResult.getId()); // create a service to get the id of previous 'subEntity'
anotherSub.setId(subEntryId);

mainEntity.setSubEntities(new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(anotherSub)));
entityManager.persist(mainEntity);
```

the concept is to update already existing entry we have to pass the id of that previous entry